# Trying to compare generated inputStream with resource file - jUnit

Tags: java, pdf, junit

I'm trying to compare the inputStream from a resource file with a created inputStream.

I'm doing that the following way:

```
InputStream isAsJpg = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("koala.jpg");
InputStream returnedIs = ImageUtil.convertImageStreamToPdfStream(isAsJpg);

//get is from src/test/resources
InputStream expectedIs = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("koala.pdf");
```

and for my tests I'm calling:

```
assertTrue(IOUtils.contentEquals(expectedIs, returnedIs));
```

but it returns false. Therefor I started with creating files so that I could manually check if the file is empty or something. So I added:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("koala", ".pdf");
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
        IOUtils.copy(returnedIs, out);
    }
```

and I have checked the content of the file manually and it seems ok. Now I wanted to created a file from the resource that I've got to check that content (on the same way) and the pdf was empty.. Although it is placed in the src/test/resource directory and when I try to open it there, it is not empty.

What am I doing wrong? It seems as if I'm not getting the resource on the correct way (koala.pdf) but I can't find an error actually..

EDIT:
When I go and look to
C:..\target\test-classes
the file is there, but.. it is empty (blank page). Although when I open it from
C:..\src\test\resources
it is not empty. How can that be??

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution.

It's possible to say to maven that he should replace Maven placeholders of type ${..} and my binary PDF content is ofc full with it and therefor the file got corrupted.

I've changed the filtering in my pom:

```
<testResources>
 <testResource>
  <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
   <filtering>false</filtering>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
```

and the file in the target/test-classes also contains the image now.

Answer (score 0):

Does this line

```
InputStream returnedIs = ImageUtil.convertImageStreamToPdfStream(isAsJpg);
```

actually write to a file? It doesn't seem like it. It seems like you should use the `InputStream` returned to write to a corresponding `OutputStream`. Then continue as you were.

Comment: The returned inputStream is used to save the file in an FTP folder. I don't want to write it to an outputStream and it's not needed. Btw, see the "EDIT" tag in the question. I've found the problem but I don't know the cause.

Comment: That sounds like a POM problem ... can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: What part might be wrong? It's a kind of big project and it has a whole POM structure with lots of lines..

Comment: Your solution below is what I was looking for and was going to suggest :)